# Orthogonal complement and quadratic form

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, orthogonality, quadratic-forms

The matrix $A\in Mat_n(\mathbb{R})$ is given by:

$$ A=\begin{pmatrix}
   2 & -1 & -1 & 0\\
   -1 & 3 & -1 & -1\\
   -1 & -1 & 3 & -1\\
   0 & -1 & -1 & 2
   \end{pmatrix}$$

and let $q: \mathbb{R^4} \to \mathbb{R}$ be the corresponding quadratic form defined by: $q(x)=x^TAx$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}^4$

Show that $q$ is positive definite on the orthogonal complement (with regard to the scalar product) to the null space $N(A)$ for A.

---

I am really uncertain if this is the right approach to the problem, but I just wanted to give it my attempt and hope that someone can guide me in the right direction.

---

I have calculated the null space $N(A) = span(\begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix})=span(\begin{pmatrix} \alpha\\ \alpha \\ \alpha \\ \alpha \end{pmatrix}) \in W$. Then I believe it is possible to form a quadratic form of $W$ by the symmetric matrix A such that: $q_{A}(W)= 2\alpha^2+3\alpha^2+3\alpha^2+2\alpha^2-10\alpha^2=0$. Which means that $q$ is negative semidefinte on $W$.

Furthermore, the positive index of inertia for $ı_+q=3$, then $q_{A}$ will be positive definite on the subspace $V$ on $\mathbb{R^4}$ and the dimension of $V$ is given by $dim⁡(V)=ı_+q=3$

$Dim⁡(N(A))=1$, in order to get the $dim⁡(V)=4$ it must be true that $dim⁡(N(A))^⊥=3$. As $q$ is negative semidefinite on $N(A)$, $q$ must be positive definite on the orthogonal complement $N(A)^⊥$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessary to go as far as orthogonal matrices for this. I am referring to Sylvester's Law of Inertia. The first column of $R$ is a basis for the kernel of $A$ as a linear transformation; the other three columns are evidently a basis for the orthogonal complement, and we see how the quadratic form acts on the orthogonal complement in the final diagonal matrix.

Let the columns of $R$ be the new basis, with
$$
R =
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
1&-1&0&1 \\
1&0&-1&-1 \\
1&0&1&-1 \\
1&1&0&1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
so that
$$
R^T R =
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
1&1&1&1 \\
-1&0&0&1 \\
0&-1&1&0 \\
1&-1&-1&1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
1&-1&0&1 \\
1&0&-1&-1 \\
1&0&1&-1 \\
1&1&0&1 \\
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
4&0&0&0 \\
0&2&0&0 \\
0&0&2&0 \\
0&0&0&4 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
and
$$
R^T A R =
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
1&1&1&1 \\
-1&0&0&1 \\
0&-1&1&0 \\
1&-1&-1&1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
2&-1&-1&0 \\
-1&3&-1&-1 \\
-1&-1&3&-1 \\
0&-1&-1&2 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
1&-1&0&1 \\
1&0&-1&-1 \\
1&0&1&-1 \\
1&1&0&1 \\
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
0&0&0&0 \\
0&4&0&0 \\
0&0&8&0 \\
0&0&0&16 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Comment: I am not sure I quite follow your method: 
So you form the matrix $R$ by the null spaces of A, but why are the columns a basis for the orthogonal complement? 
The Sylvesters Law of Inertia in my textbook is as follows: 
"Let $q=q_A$ be a quadratic form on $\mathbb{R^n}$, which is represented by the real symmetric matrix A. Additionally let $V = (v_1, ... v_n)$ be a basis for $\mathbb{R^n}$, and let $c_1,...,c_n \in {-1,0,1}$ be integers such that $q(x_1\cdot v_1 + ... x_n \cdot v_n) = c_1\cdot {x_1^2} + ... + c_n \cdot {x_n^2}$ so $ı_+q,ı_-q = c_i$ is equal to 1 and -1 respectively"

Comment: Wouldn't the last column be (1,-2,0,1) if the columns are the eigenvectors for the $\mathbb{R^4}$ ?

Comment: @MadsJeppesen  you should calculate my $AR$ by hand. It is just a multiplication of integer matrices.

Comment: Sorry I was unclear in that comment, I mean shouldn't the last column in $R$ be $(1,-2,0,1)^T$ as I assume $R$ is a basis for $\mathbb{R^4}$ consisting of the eigenvectors - which was found by calculating the Null space of A's eigenvalues.

Comment: @MadsJeppesen the 4 eigenspace is two dimensional. I picked a basis I liked. You can confirm that I picked eigenvectors very easily. In particular, the column vector you want is the sum of my third and fourth columns

Comment: One last question: When you calculate the diagonal matrix shouldn't it be $R^{-1}AR$ and not the transpose of R